# Presenting UIAlertController increases UILabel font size inside UIToolbar in iOS 11

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, uialertcontroller, uitoolbar

I have an issue with font size of UILabel, which is programmatically added in UIToolbar:

```
- (UILabel *)createTitleLabel
{
  UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(_topToolbar.frame)/3, CGRectGetHeight(_topToolbar.frame))];
 label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
 label.textColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.1 alpha:1.0];
 label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
 label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialMT" size:18];
 label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
 label.minimumScaleFactor = 0.8;
 label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
 return label;
}

// -----
UILabel *label = [self createTitleLabel];
self.titleLabel = label;
[self.topToolbar insertItem:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:label] atIndex:_topToolbar.items.count/2 animated:NO];

// ------ code for adding item to toolbar
- (void)insertItem:(UIBarItem *)barItem atIndex:(NSUInteger)index animated:(BOOL)animated
{
 NSMutableArray *toolbarItems = [self.items mutableCopy];
 NSAssert(index <= toolbarItems.count, @"Invalid index for toolbar item");
 [toolbarItems insertObject:barItem atIndex:index];
 [self setItems:toolbarItems animated:animated];
}
```

After setting a bit large text to title label, it works as expected, font is reduced, and tail is truncated, but when I present UIAlertController, this font is getting larger, and UILabel width is growing, which hides other bar button items inside toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

Beginning with iOS 11, views added to toolbars as UIBarButtonItem using `customView` initializer are now laid out using auto layout. You should add sizing constraints on your `label`. For example:

```
[label.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:CGRectGetWidth(_topToolbar.frame)/3].active = YES;
[label.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:CGRectGetHeight(_topToolbar.frame)].active = YES;
```

Otherwise, auto layout will use the intrinsic content size of your label which is causing the `label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;` to be ignored. Sizing likely works initially because adding a bar button item doesn't trigger a layout pass, however presenting and dismissing another view controller will cause auto layout to perform a pass for your view controller's entire view hierarchy.

For more information see the WWDC 2017 session [Updating your app for iOS 11](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/204/).